# D3 Force Layout - Custom collapse, uncollapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, force-layout, directed-graph

I am using d3's force layout to create a custom collapse mechanism where the nodes collapse towards the parent node and are arranged in a cluster behind it. THis is using the normal FOrce layout with a JSON having nodes and links. I have managed to get the layout to collapse and cluster towards the main node, but as soon as the transition is done, it re-sets the nodes back to their original position. I have a feeling this has something to do with the tick() function.

Here is my code to collapse the nodes and links. (px, py) is the point they cluster towards.

```
currentNode.transition()
           .duration(2000)
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + px + "," + py + ")");

currentLink.transition()
           .duration(2000)
           .attr("x2", px)
           .attr("y2", py);
```

In the tick function, I have the following:

```
force.on("tick", function () {
            link.attr("x1", function (currLink) {
                return currLink.source.x;
            })
                .attr("y1", function (currLink) {
                    return currLink.source.y;
                })
                .attr("x2", function (currLink) {
                    return currLink.target.x;
                })
                .attr("y2", function (currLink) {
                    return currLink.target.y;
                });

            node.attr("transform", function (currNode) {
                return "translate(" + currNode.x + "," + currNode.y + ")";
            });
        });
```

Is there something terribly silly that I'm missing out here? Thanks.

Comment: Before collapsing/expanding, call `force.stop()` to stop the simulation.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the immediate resetting after the collapse event. However, I am now finding that dragging any node (even non related ones) in the graph causes the collapsed nodes to be reset. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: Depends on how you're doing the dragging. Could you post a complete working example please?